# 32Bit DLL not building properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, 32bit-64bit

We have a c# executable that loads a 32bit dll written in C++ which dynamically loads another 32bit dll (the first dll is a wrapper).

When this is built on a 32bit machine (with VS toolset v100) it all works correctly.

When it is built on a 64bit machine (with VS toolset v110) it runs on some machines, but on others it gets a FileNotFoundException on the wrapper dll. It works on some 64bit machines, fails on some and fails on at least one 32bit machine.

The failure happens in Assembly.LoadFrom, where the location comes from Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location. The dll is in the same dir as the exe, which was build as x86.

If build on a 64bit machine to get a failing version, then I drop in a version of the wrapper dll built on a 32bit machine, it works properly (so it's not really a file not found problem, but rather a 'correct' file not found one).

Any ideas why this is failing? Is it the build machine, or the toolset? Or something else? Is there something I can set in the build to get it working properly (I'd like to continue building on a 64bit box)?

Comment: I'm assuming you have your output platform for the C# executable set to x86 and not AnyCPU?

Comment: Yes. But the weird part is that I'm getting the same problem on a 32bit machine (and working on some 64bit boxes). I've been suspicious that the problem is not a 32 vs 64 issue. I've dumped both dlls, but they appear identical (and there are no code changes).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all dependency dlls installed on the client machines? Like VC Runtime, other libraries you depend on?